# MySQL innerjoin 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

Supposing I had 3 tables

- Passenger (Id [pk], name)
- Airplane (registration [pk], num_seats)
- Booking (Id, **passenger_id** *[fk -> Passenger.Id]*, **airplane_registration** *[fk -> Airplane.registration]*)

The booking table would be a junction object here as there is a many to many relationship between tables Passenger and Booking.

How could I select all the details related to a particular booking id (say 'abcde')?

Is this correct:

```
SELECT Passenger.name, Airplane.num_seats, Booking.Id
  FROM Booking 
  JOIN Passenger ON Passenger.Id = Booking.passenger_Id
  JOIN Airplane ON Booking.airplane_registration = Airplane.registration
 WHERE Booking.Id = 'abcde';
```

Is this the right way to do it?
Also, If I wanted to select all bookings and their details, would I do it the same way? (Without the where clause)?

I was looking to find out if this was correct for a test as MySQL has gone down on my machine.

Comment: Hi OMG Ponies, did I make a mistake with the formatting? If so, what did I do wrong? Thanks

Comment: Salutations (IE: Hi) and platitudes (IE: thanks) are a waste of screen real estate (and if the acceptance rating is below 50% - insulting).  I try to improve readability when I can - more likely you'll get help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your query would work for getting the details of the passengers and the flight for the particular booking ID. For getting all bookings, I would add an ORDER BY bookingID and if needed by passenger name and flight registration.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your schema, there's no way to be sure, but that looks just fine to me.

Comment: Hi there. Apologies for not clarifying. I've updated my original post. As you can see, the Booking table contains 2 foreign keys. The first references the primary key 'Id' in table Passenger and the second references the primary key 'registration' in table Airplane.